# Items Unique To Ice Biome?

Tags: terraria

I've been moving along my progression line at a brisk pace in Terraria lately, all the way up to a full set of Crimsonite Armor and weapons, a Minishark (I prefer it until I get a better supply of stars for the Star Canon), and basically all the meteorite equipment I want.  I'm ready to take on the Dungeon, but there's one biome I have yet to fully explore...

My Underground Ice Biome.

This is a bit ironic, since I decided to move my home on top of that biome, but I only ever explored the depths of it a little bit one time, and while that got me a nice Ice Boomerang and a Frost In A Bottle, I hardly ever use the Boomerang anymore and I don't think I'll need more than one X in a bottle from there.

Is there any reason to further explore my underground Ice Biome?  Are there any unique items I'd be missing by going straight to the dungeon and, from there, the sky and eventually down to Hell?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are missing much: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Snow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unique items in chests

- Underground

  - Ice Boomerang
  - Ice Blade
  - Ice Skates
  - Snowball Cannon
  - Blizzard in a Bottle
  - Flurry Boots

### Unique items as drops

- Surface

  - Frost Helmet
  - Frost Breastplate
  - Frost Leggings
  - Ice Feather
  - Frost Staff
  - Eskimo vanity set
- Underground

  - Snowball Launcher
  - Ice Sickle
  - Viking Helmet
  - Frozen Turtle Shell
  - Frost Staff

In addition there are banners for some (if not all) of the unique enemies.

Comment: What about the Eskimo Coat and Pants that I got from all the Eskimo Zombies I killed during a bloodmoon?

Comment: @Zibbobz indeed, forgot